# Need to use several comboboxes in JPanel (Java Swing)

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I need to filter data from MySQL db in JTable using several comboboxes. I used one combobox and want to use another one.
I would appreciate it if somebody could help me to figure out how to add one more combobox. Below is the piece of my code with one combobox; the code is runnable but i need to add one more combobox and coudn't find a correct decision how to do that.
Thank you in advance!

```
 public void findTours()
    {
   ArrayList<Tour> tours= ListTours((String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    model.setColumnIdentifiers (new Object[]{"Tour Type", "Food", "Accomodation", "Name", "Price($)"});
    Object[] row = new Object[5];
    for(int i=0; i< tours.size();i++)
    {
        row[0]=tours.get(i).getTourtype();
        row[1]=tours.get(i).getFood();
        row[2]=tours.get(i).getAccomodation();
        row[3]=tours.get(i).getName();
           row[4]=tours.get(i).getPrice();
        model.addRow(row);

  }
   JTable_Search.setModel(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> but i need to add one more combobox

Your code doesn't even add a single combo box so what is the point of the posted code?

Where do you want to see these multiple combo boxes:

1. In the same column but a different row
2. In a different column

Be explicit when you ask a question so we don't have to guess what you are thinking.

Here is an example that shows how to add a different combo box by row:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableComboBoxByRow extends JPanel
{
    List<String[]> editorData = new ArrayList<String[]>(3);

    public TableComboBoxByRow()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        // Create the editorData to be used for each row

        editorData.add( new String[]{ "Red", "Blue", "Green" } );
        editorData.add( new String[]{ "Circle", "Square", "Triangle" } );
        editorData.add( new String[]{ "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" } );

        //  Create the table with default data

        Object[][] data =
        {
            {"Color", "Red"},
            {"Shape", "Square"},
            {"Fruit", "Banana"},
            {"Plain", "Text"}
        };
        String[] columnNames = {"Type","Value"};

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        JTable table = new JTable(model)
        {
            //  Determine editor to be used by row
            public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column)
            {
                int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel( column );

                if (modelColumn == 1 && row < 3)
                {
                    JComboBox<String> comboBox1 = new JComboBox<String>( editorData.get(row));
                    return new DefaultCellEditor( comboBox1 );
                }
                else
                    return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
            }
        };

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        add( scrollPane );
    }
    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Combo Box by Row");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new TableComboBoxByRow() );
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If you want it in a different column then read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for an example.

Keep a link to the tutorial handy for all Swing basics.